# MySQL - update with inner join is creating nulls

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am trying to do an update of values from one stock table into another stock table.  However, some of the values are getting copied over as `NULL` because that stock does not exist in the source table.  I thought that `INNER JOIN` only looked at the values that were shared between both tables.  My `allStocks` table has a lot more stocks than `divStocks`, but there are a few stocks in `divStocks` that don't exist in `allStocks`.  I just want to copy the prices over from `allStocks` into `divStocks` and not overwrite any prices with `NULL`.

This is my current query:

```
UPDATE `divStocks` ds INNER JOIN `allStocks` als ON
`ds`.`tickerSymbol` = `als`.`tickerSymbol` SET `ds`.`price` =
`als`.`price`, `ds`.`priceAsOf` = `als`.`priceAsOf`;
```

Comment: Are you sure the ticker symbos doesn't exist on both sides, and it is jus the price that is missing?

Comment: The ticker does not exist in the source table (`allStocks`) so the price becomes `NULL` in `divStocks`.

Comment: "not overwrite any prices with NULL" -- Do you mean that if divStocks already has a NULL price, don't change it?  (I suspect you meant something else.)

Comment: I mean before the query, the price in `divStocks` is a specific decimal, ex: 34.02.  After the query if that ticker does not exist in `allStocks`, that price gets overwritten with `NULL`.

Comment: Please post some sample data, to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: This is an `INNER JOIN`, so if `ds.tickerSymbol` does not match in `allStocks` the row is **not** updated. So check your data because the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Dah!  Nevermind, I was wiping out the values myself!  I'll close this, sorry guys!

Comment: i m wondering your als . tickerSymbol got duplicated rows which contains null data.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Please format your code reasonably. Read the edit help re code blocks. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the simplest solution would be to add a `WHERE` to your query to specifically rule out rows that don't have a price in the `allStocks` table. Doing it this way adds to the readability of the query as compared to using something like a `RIGHT JOIN` which is fairly uncommon.

```
UPDATE `divStocks` ds 
INNER JOIN `allStocks` als ON `ds`.`tickerSymbol` = `als`.`tickerSymbol` 
SET `ds`.`price` = `als`.`price`, `ds`.`priceAsOf` = `als`.`priceAsOf`
WHERE `als`.`price` IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COALESCE` to handle cases that values in `allStocks` are nullable.

```
UPDATE `divStocks` ds 
INNER JOIN `allStocks` als ON `ds`.`tickerSymbol` = `als`.`tickerSymbol` 
SET `ds`.`price` = COALESCE(`als`.`price`,`ds`.`price`)
   ,`ds`.`priceAsOf` = COALESCE(`als`.`priceAsOf`,`ds`.`priceAsOf`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update records from `divStocks` table which only exist in `allStocks` table you should use `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. For example:

```
UPDATE `divStocks` ds 
RIGHT JOIN `allStocks` als ON `ds`.`tickerSymbol` = `als`.`tickerSymbol` 
SET `ds`.`price` = `als`.`price`, `ds`.`priceAsOf` = `als`.`priceAsOf`;
```

Answer (score 0):

IFNULL? That is IF you want to keep as an Inner Join

```
UPDATE `divStocks` ds 
INNER JOIN `allStocks` als ON`ds`.`tickerSymbol` = `als`.`tickerSymbol`
SET `ds`.`price` = IFNULL(`als`.`price`, `ds`.`priceAsOf`), 
`ds`.`priceAsOf` = IFNULL(`als`.`priceAsOf`, `ds`.`priceAsOf`);
```